# Can CONS objects be used as a key to a hash table?

Tags: lisp, common-lisp, gnu-common-lisp

I've been playing with LISP lately, and I want to attempted to optimize a terribly inefficient recursive function by caching it's output so it only runs each combination of parameters once. I want to save the results into hash table, using either `(LIST a b)` or `(CONS a b)` as the key. My question is, is that even possible? Documentation I've read would lead me to believe it is, as the document I read defines the `key` as an 'object', and defines 'object' as something that was constructed with `cons`. So I gave this a try.

```
(defparameter *table* (make-hash-table))
(setf (gethash (list 1 2) *table*) 123)
(format t "~S~%" (gethash (list 1 2) *table*))
```

And it gives me `NIL`, when I would expect `123`. If i replace the `(list 1 2)` with a `cons` it still doesn't work, but when I use an plain integer, it works fine.

I'm using GCL 2.6.12

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(make-hash-table :test #'equal)
```

Comment: Works like a charm. What's the default value of `test`?

Comment: http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_mk_has.htm "test---a designator for one of the functions eq, eql, equal, or equalp. The default is eql."

Comment: Oh goddamn. I had that exact page open, I swear, but I skipped the section where it gives the default. I guess that's what I get for not RTFM. *walks away in shame*

Comment: Keep in mind that eql is often the default in many functions.

Comment: If you use the same cons, the default test should work, right?

Answer (score 0):

Solutions for caching results of functions has been already implemented for Common Lisp. One is library fare-memoization, the second is function-cache and both are accessible with the Quicklisp. Using the former is as easy as defining normal function:

```
(define-memo-function your-time-consuming-function (arg)
    (code arg))
```

For reference please check https://github.com/fare/fare-memoization.